# Why aren't compiler flags I specify in my makefile showing up in my terminal (Cygwin) output?

Tags: c, makefile, terminal, cygwin

So I'm trying to run C code with a Cygwin terminal and I have a makefile called Makefile.mak with the following in it:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean:
    rm -f ex3
```

The book I have "Learn C the Hard Way" says I need to use the command "make clean", however, when I write this I get the error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
```

It only works if I type

```
make -f Makefile.mak clean."
```

The next problem is that when I try the make command on my C file (ex3.c) I get the output

```
cc     ex3.c   -o ex3
```

yet I am supposed to see the flags in that output from my makefile as well. Like this:

```
cc -Wall -g   ex3.c   -o ex3.
```

I've tried changing the settings in my gcc compiler and still nothing.

I also have the makefile and my C code file in the same file path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Name the file `Makefile`. That is - without `.mak`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you learn to add `.mak` to the filename?

Comment: @HAL9000 I thought that was just how makefiles were supposed to be.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you good sir! This worked!

Comment: @Slick, so you just did a bad guess then. Nothing to be ashamed of.. I was afraid I had to put your book on the to-burn list....

Comment: @HAL9000 Yah the book explicitly says just name the file Makefile. I got confused by the heading "ex2.1.mak" I guess haha

Answer (score 0):

The filename Makefile.mak is not picked up by `make` by default.  You need to name it either "makefile" or "Makefile" for that.

As for the compile command, you didn't specify a target on how to build ex3.  You need to add that:

```
ex3: ex3.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: No, the `make` command should already know how to compile `.c` files into executables. You don't need those lines. Actually you don't need a makefile *at all* if you only want to compile with default options. And if you *do* include those lines, you should also  add `$(CPPFLAGS)`, `$(LDFLAGS)` and maybe a few others.